# Cannnot run Mongoose on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongosh

- Error Message:
- When running Mongoose, I encounter the following error message:

---

```
[nodemon] 3.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
/home/harithriyadh/prayer-    
tracker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/admin.js:62
        session: options?.session,
                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js         
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/harithriyadh/prayer-    
tracker/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js:6:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

---

- DB Connection File:
- Here is the file responsible for connecting to the database:

---

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dbUrl =     
"mongodb+srv://username:password@harith.pl58u3c.mongodb.net/?           
retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const connectionParams = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}; 

mongoose
.connect(dbUrl, connectionParams)
.then(() => {
    console.info("Connected to the DB");
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log("Error:", e);
});
```

---

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) wasn't supported until Node v14.5. See [Node Green](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----) for reference. You need to upgrade your Node version for a whole host of reasons let alone this one.

Comment: The error is in `node_modules/mongodb/lib/admin.js:62`, so clearly your version of node isn't compatible with your version of mongodb